# IAM Tag Policy with Condition

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am trying to create an IAM policy that gives a user full admin rights to all EC2 and RDS resources tagged with sf_env:dev.

I can't seem to figure out the syntax.

The AWS policy simulator displayed
Parse error on line 10: ..._env":"dev"}}}]}{"Statement": [{"A -------------------^ Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got '{'

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [{
"Action": "ec2:*",
"Effect": "Allow",
"Resource": "*",
"Condition": {"StringEquals": {"ec2:ResourceTag/sf_env":"dev"}}
}
]
}
{
"Statement": [{
"Action": "rds:"*",
"Effect": "Allow",
"Resource": "*",
"Condition": {"StringEquals": {"ec2:ResourceTag/sf_env":"dev"}}
}
]
}
```

Comment: That is invalid JSON, you are missing a comma between a closing `}` and an opening `{` . Try using a linting tool like http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I used the AWS policy simulator which also checks your syntax automatically. I used this article to find out what I did wrong. http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx1LYOT2FQML4UG/-Back-to-School-Understanding-the-IAM-span-class-matches-Policy-span-Grammar. I had multiple policy statements in one statement block which was an issue. I made one policy block with a single statement of arrays.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "ec2:ResourceTag/sf_env": "dev"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "rds:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "ec2:ResourceTag/sf_env": "dev"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}